# How to get PayPal client-side info to Django?

Tags: django, paypal

I am using PayPal standard IPN payment solution in client side in my Django web app.

```
<body>
    <!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

    <!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD"></script>

    <script>
        // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
        paypal.Buttons({

            // Set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [{
                        amount: {
                            value: '88.44'
                        }
                    }]
                });
            },

            // Finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
                    // Successful capture! For demo purposes:
                    console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                    
                });
            }


        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
</body>
```

everything works fine and I can access all the data through the details variable **in the js code**.

Now, i need to insert the details **into django db**, no api, simple model.

Tried many things, none worked.
I prefer not to use django-paypal because it doesn't have smart buttons (as far as i saw) and there is only option for "buy now button" and no credit / debit card.

how can it be done? or is there smart buttons for django-paypal package?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am also struggling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get PayPal client-side info to Django?

Don't.

An integration that creates and captures payments with client-side JS functions is for very simple use cases. It should never be used if you need to do anything automated with the result, such as writing transaction results to a database.

Instead, API-based integrations exist for precisely this use case. Use the v2/checkout/orders API and make two routes (url paths) on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order'. You could use the Checkout-PHP-SDK for the routes' API calls to PayPal, or your own HTTPS implementation of first getting an access token and then doing the call. Both of these routes should return/output **only** JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should verify the amount was correct and store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as reserving product or sending an email) immediately *before* forwarding return JSON to the frontend caller. In the event of an error forward the JSON details of it as well, since the frontend must handle such cases.

Pair those 2 routes with this frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server .  (If you need to send any additional data from the client to the server, such as an items array or selected options, add a `body` parameter to the fetch with a value that is a JSON string or object)